# Azure and plotting data

Tags: azure, plot, iot

Does azure have its own facilities to draw income date from IoT device (say Y-axis for temperature, X-axis for timestamp) in real-time (or not in real-time)

I was able to implement it using PowerBI, but this is an external tool.
Also I know it is possible to publish it to your own web application, but again, it is an external application.
Does azure have any internal "on-portal" tools to do the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Time Time Series Insighs (TSI) for this purpose. Setup can be done with a few klicks from the Azure portal. It supports Azure IoT Hub or EventHubs as a source. In the IoT Hub you should configure a separate consumer group (Endpoints/EventEndpoints). TSI supports JSON as serialization format. See the [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/tutorial-create-populate-tsi-environment) for the complete setup.

Comment: Great! I set up it. But it is not real-time displaying, is it?